# Displaying data on view blade from database Laravel Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new with working laravel. I have faced with a problem, when I am trying to display data on website using laravel notification.
This is my code:

GameBiddedNotification.php:

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return[
        'title' => $this->details['title'],
        'text' => $this->details['text']
    ];
}
```

This is database template, in data column:

```
{"title":"hg","text":"\u10db\u10dd\u10d7\u10d0\u10db\u10d0\u10e8\u10d4 \u10e8\u10d4\u10db\u10dd\u10d5\u10d8\u10d3\u10d0"}
```

And this is my blade:

```
                  @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
              @php
              $data = json_decode($notification,true);
              $test = $data['title'] ['text'];
              @endphp

              <a class="dropdown-item preview-item">
                <div class="preview-thumbnail">
                  <div class="preview-icon bg-dark rounded-circle">
                    <i class="mdi mdi-xbox-controller text-success"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="preview-item-content">
                  {{-- <p class="preview-subject mb-1">{{ $notification->data['title'] }}</p> --}}
                  <p class="text-muted ellipsis mb-0">{{ $test }}</p>
                </div>
              </a>
              @endforeach
```

I have tried multiple methods for example:

```
{{ $notification->data['title'] }}
```

, but result is the same. I am getting always an error saying

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined index: title
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, title and text is stored in 'data' column,

```
   @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification) 
        <a class="dropdown-item preview-item">
            <div class="preview-thumbnail">
                <div class="preview-icon bg-dark rounded-circle">
                    <i class="mdi mdi-xbox-controller text-success"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="preview-item-content">
                <p class="preview-subject mb-1">{{ $notification->data['title'] }}</p>
                <p class="text-muted ellipsis mb-0">{{ $notification->data['text'] }}</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: it throws an error: "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check it once.

Comment: hmm, "Undefined index: text".

Answer (score 0):

If you set up `$casts` properly on Notification-model to cast data-column as array, there is no need to use json_decode on blade.

`$casts = [ 'data' => 'array' ];`

What does your model look like?

btw: You should generally avoid `@php` — it usually points out code that belongs in the controller. I suppose this is test-only code? Instead, better `dd($notification);` to check data-attribute.